# How does Wordpress create slugs?

Tags: php, wordpress, slug

I am writing a script to import posts from a CSV file, but I need to generate a slug from the data source in order to query Wordpress to see if the post already exists, how does Wordpress generate the slugs? I will need to generate the slugs in the exact same way in order to correctly query the Wordpress database.

Comment: Please share your internet research efforts, the community won't do that for you :-)
See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, you can use the function sanitize_title().